# cannot get to read from extraResources after pack with electron builder

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Im working with a app, that read/write from json files located in the `extraResources` directory, created by electron-builder

Package.json

```
"build": {
      "files": [
        "src/*",
        "src/json/*",
        "src/scss/*",
        "src/views/*"
      ],
      "extraResources": [
          {
            "from": "./src/json/",
            "to": "extraResources",
            "filter": [
              "**/*"
            ]
          }
      ],
      "win": {
        "target": "nsis",
        "icon": "build/icon.ico"
      }
    }
```

Im trying to read the json file from Tasks.json with this

```
const loadTasks = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'extraResources', "Tasks.json"))
```

But when compile, i'm getting this error message in the console:
`Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/extraResources/Tasks.json'`

i dont know what i'm doing wrong, but i cannot access extraResources, that is located outsite of app.asar

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `electron-builder` [documentation](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents.html#extraresources), `extraResources` is located in the app's resources directory

> A glob patterns relative to the project directory, when specified, copy the file or directory with matching names directly into the app’s resources directory (Contents/Resources for MacOS, resources for Linux and Windows).

You can get the resources directory by using [`process.resourcesPath`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/process#processresourcespath-readonly)

```js
path.join(process.resourcesPath, YOUR_EXTRA_RESOURCES_FILES);
```